# Get clipboard value for data validation

Tags: excel, vba, validation, copy-paste

I have an Excel file, where in a specific range of cells, if a change is made, a change event macro is triggered.

This macro checks if the last action is any type of pasting.

I need to get, in a variable the content the user has copied (clipboard?) and then execute a function or procedure which checks the validy of the data. If it's correct, it will paste the values mantaining the conditional format, and if wrong it will undo the operation and disable the events.

I stated range(B:B) to keep it simple. In reality I will have a function for each column because the validation changes. (I will replicate the logic.)

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    lastAction = Application.CommandBars("Standard").FindControl(ID:=128).List(1)
    
    If Left(lastAction, 5) = "Paste" Then
        If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("B:B")) Is Nothing Then
            validation (Application.Intersect(Target, Range("B:B")))
        End If
    Else
    End If
End Sub


Function validation(cell) As Boolean
    Dim check As Boolean
    check = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cell, MDM.Range("AK2:AK86"), 1, False)
    If check = True Then
        ActiveSheets.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllMergingConditionalFormats
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Else
        With Application
            .EnableEvents = False
            .Undo
        End With
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Function
```

I need to do this validation because if the user pastes the value from another Excel file, it will remove both the conditional formatting and the data validation for that column.

[image]

Comment: This should help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/Concepts/Windows-API/retrieve-information-from-the-clipboard

Comment: Why not just reapply the Condition Formatting and Data Validation when the user pastes and the Conditional Formatting and Data Validation aren't present?  That way the user isn't restricted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used the clsClipboard class described at the following link

```
http://www.la-solutions.co.uk/content/CONNECT/MVBA/MVBA-Clipboard.htm
```

Copy the VBA class module code to a file named clsClipboard.cls, then import new Class module into your project.

Usage:

```
Sub test()
    Dim CB As New clsClipboard
    Dim myVar As String

    CB.SetText "this is a test"

    myVar = CB.GetText()

    Debug.Print myVar
    
    Set CB = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello @exception, in my hypothetical case, CB.GetText woul be called without setting the text before (cause it's dynamic), right?

Comment: Correct!  Whatever happens to be in your clipboard (text) will be returned by CB.GetText().

Comment: And it's mandatory to clean the clipboard content as I see after each use, right?

Comment: No.  Not mandatory.  It's entirely up to you...

Comment: Set CB = Nothing only releases the referencing variable.  It does not affect the clipboard at all...

Comment: thanks @exceptionm it works. the only downside is that somehow I am getting a blank line below the clipboard. This makes the string not to be equal to the input copied by the end users. Any ideas how to sort this out? Some kind of trim?

Comment: When you copy a cell in Excel, Excel seems to append <cr><lf> pair.  You might try Replace(<your clipboard var>, vbCrLf, "")...